# Quick way to create array from another array's variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have 2 arrays:

```
var a = [];
var b = [];

a.push({id:1, name:"Joe"});
a.push({id:2, name:"Jeff"});
a.push({id:3, name:"John"});
```

Is there a quick way to populate `b` with just `a`'s names in Javascript, or do I have to use a loop?

E.g, something like:

```
b = a[].name;    // b is now ["Joe","Jeff","John"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can say:

```
var b = $.map(a, function(val, i) { return val.name; });
```

[jQuery's `$.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) is equivalent to JavaScript's own [`Array.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), except the latter is a relatively new feature of JS and so doesn't work in older browsers (i.e., pre-IE9).

Comment: I like this solution better than a loop, we're using jQuery and I def. prefer a convenience function over having to write another g-damned loop

Comment: Cool. Obviously if you had some code that needed to be ultra-efficient you'd write your own loop to save all the function calls, but for "normal" cases it's much nicer to let `.map()` hide the looping from you.

Answer (score 3):

A loop must be used in some form.  Either by your code or by a function you call to do the copy of specific elements.  The solution using say `map` still uses a loop under the hood

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  b.push(a[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about older browsers you can use the [ES5 `map` method](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.19):

```
b = a.map(function(elem) {
    return elem.name;
});
```

If you do care about older browsers, you can polyfill the `map` method ([MDN provides a decent polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) or you can use a normal loop, as you suggest (although obviously the `map` method uses some form of loop anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to loop. There are various collections manipulation functions now baked into the language. One if them that would be useful here is `map`.

```
var b = a.map(function(person) {
    return person.name;
});
```

Checkout the [`Underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore) library that makes a lot of operations like this easy. It has a method named `pluck` that would be ideal here.

```
var b = _.pluck(a, 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate through a in order to produce a new array in b with each name.

Answer (score 0):

It requires a loop, but there are library functions that can abstract the looping away for you. I'm partial to using [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) for these types of things (and I generally get it for free since I use Backbone liberally) but you can find similar functions in JQuery such as [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)